# How can i make it so that only administrator can install software?

Tags: windows-vista

How can i make it so that only administrator can install software? Dont want the kids installing software on the computer as they always press yes to everything that pops up

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "install software".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the kids an account, and make it only a Standard User. Problem solved

Comment: I installed Quake 3 and played it over the network on a similarly competently "locked down" corporate laptop a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control panel ->User accounts and family safety->Add or remove accounts

now create new account , while choosing select **Standard account** .

If your kids tries to install software or something it will ask for password of administrator account .

[image]

The parental controls options built into Windows Vista help us to determine which games  children can play, which programs they can use, and which websites they can visit—and when. So we can restrict computer use to specific times and Windows will restrict those options

Comment: Doesn't restrict software that runs without installer, probably all "portable apps".